# simple Or statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to do a simple or statement in a controller

This generates one set of trips that I am interested in displaying and is working fine.

```
@trips = Trip.where(:userid => @friends)
```

However, i would like to add another set of trips; trips whose userid == current_user.id

```
@trips = Trip.where(:userid => current_user.id)
```

Trying to combine these two i tried...

```
@trips = Trip.where(:conditions => ['userid= ? OR userid=?', @friends, current_user.id])
```

Any idea where the bust is?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply pass an array to get the equivalent of the SQL `WHERE ... IN` clause.

```
Trip.where(userid: [@friends, current_user.id])
```

See the [ActiveRecord Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html), 2.3.3 Subset Conditions

Answer (score 0):

Is `@friends` an array? ActiveRecord will convert your where statement into a SQL `IN` clause when you generate it with the hash syntax. When you build your OR statement in raw SQL, you need to do the `IN` manually.

`@trips = Trip.where('userid IN ? OR userid = ?', @friends, current_user.id)`

Also, your column is called `userid` ? Typicaly it would be called `user_id` - is this a typo or do you just have an abnormal database?